# Как присобачить ajax

Tags: url, ajax, php, html5-history-api

Как добавить на свой сайт ajax чтобы менялась страница только в <div class="content"> и была история url? Так как у меня на сайте имеются get post запросы и история url мне нужна.Как реализована на ВК

Answer (score 1):

К примеру для замены содержимого <div class="content"> в AJAX вызывается content.php . Добавьте в content.php код который будет записывать в бд параметры с которыми вызывался этот файл + session key пользователя или его ip адрес . В итоге полученные данные можно будет использовать для получения статистики просмотренных страниц.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone.js: его [Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) и поддержка history api.

Comment: для этого Backbone ? не ядерной ли бомбой это по комарам ?

Comment: Ядерной. Раз возникла мысль ajax'ифицировать сайт, только на диве и истории дело вряд ли остановится. А сложность и ядерность не ощутится, надеюсь. Почему бы не заодно не приобщиться к хорошему фрейворку постепенно.

Comment: мне для фронта ангуляр больше понравился. Если честно не нашел у себя мотивацию писать с backbone, может не осилил или задачи не те.

Comment: В нашем проекте я бэкендом занимаюсь, а ко-фаундер фронтендит, вот, на backbone, marionette с require и прочими модными штучками. Просто доверяю его экспертному выбору. Сам использую bb только в своём игрушечном сайд-проекте аппа для ВК, кажется очень логичным и «правильным».

Касательно этого вопроса — почему никто до сих пор не порекомендовал какую-то из «лёгких» библитек для той же history с graceful degrade на случай неподдержки?  history.js, плагины jQuery какие-нибудь? Я просто не работал с ними.

Comment: да я уже тыщу раз отвечал на такой вопрос, даже демку простую сделал,

Comment: так может, закрыть с вердиктом «повтор вопроса [ссылка на вопрос]»?

Comment: [вот здесь](/questions/218272/)